# TYPO3 File as .txt or .ts?

Tags: typo3, phpstorm, typoscript

I build a TYPO3 Extension. And I use for the TypoScript Folder the Files as .ts. For the IDE PhpStorm is this better I use .ts.

But I see in other Extensions the File as .txt.

What is better?

Comment: I guess the problem is: `.ts` file extension is already used for TypeScript. IDE cannot associate the same extension to different file types. You can reassign it from one file type to another but this will be an IDE-wide setting (affects all projects). The `.txt` could be used here to avoid such issues, **I guess**, or if no TYPO3 plugin is installed. If you need support for both TypoScript and TypeScript -- better create custom extension of TypoScript (e.g. `.typos` or whatever).

Comment: I'm using *.ts See also https://decisions.typo3.org/t/file-endings-for-typoscript-files-and-tsconfig-files/43/20

Comment: or i can use .t3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the file ending `.typoscript` for newer TYPO3 versions.

This was introduced in TYPO3 8.7, see changelog: [Feature: #78161 - Introduce .typoscript file extension](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/8.7.x/Feature-78161-IntroduceTypoScriptFileExtension.html)

Using .txt was deprecated in 9.3, see Changelog [Deprecation: #81686 - Accessing core TypoScript with .txt file extension has been deprecated](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/9.5/en-us/Changelog/9.3/Deprecation-81686-AccessingCoreTypoScriptWithTxtFileExtensionHasBeenDeprecated.html)

As already mentioned, .ts is not such a good idea as it is used for Typescript.

See also the official [TypoScript coding guidelines](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/CodingGuidelines/CglTypoScript/Index.html)

Comment: Yes, thanks, for the TYPO3 9 and 10 we should to use the ending .typoscript !

Answer (score 4):

There was a voting recently at [decisions.typo3.org](https://decisions.typo3.org/t/file-endings-for-typoscript-and-tsconfig-files-results/71) to agree on a file extension for TypoScript files.

> This voting relates to how to distinguish between TSconfig (User + Page), TypoScript and defining best practices
>   to be used completely throughout the TYPO3 Core.

**`.typoscript`** was voted for by two thirds of participators. If it‘s really a decision and not a mere poll then that‘s what TYPO3 core will be heading for. Refer to the voting to see further details like how to distinguish between TypoScript and TSConfig.

Answer (score 1):

I use the TypoScript Plug-In from Stefan Galinski in PhpStorm. In preferences I add the following file types:

- *.t3c for Constants
- *.t3s for Setup
- *.ts for TSconfig

So I can load constants and setup files from same folder.

**Template Constants**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:fileadmin/TypoScript" extensions="t3c">
```

**Template Setup**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:fileadmin/TypoScript" extensions="t3s">
```

**Page TSConfig**

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:fileadmin/TSconfig/Page" extensions="ts">
```